# Discord.js Embed Builder Error (.description field required)

Tags: discord.js

When trying to send a Discord.js embed, I'm getting a "DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0].description: This field is required" error. Does anyone know why this is happening? I suspect this might be an issue with the source code. I'm using Discord.js v13, and I copied the embed straight off of the Discord.js guide website:

```
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(0x0099FF)
.setTitle('Some title')
.setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
.setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
.setDescription('Some description here')
.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
.addFields(
    { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
    { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
)
.addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

outputChannel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the problem is from color: try `.setColor('WHITE')`

Comment: If you have `discord.js@13.x.x`, then you are using the wrong code. This is how you would send an embed in `discord.js@14.x.x`. This is the v13 guide => [discord.js v13 Guide](https://v13.discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `EmbedBuilder` in discord.js v13 because this is a discord.js v14 constructor.
 Just change it to `MessageEmbed` and it should work.